# How to add CardView to the Parent Layout of an itemview at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically i've a recyclerview and i want to add a cardview to any item that is click from recyclerview.
my recyclcerview has only a Textview and an Image with Linear layout as parentLayout and i want to add Cardview as parent layout for Linear layout on click of any item from RecyclerView.

Comment: For title:-  `TextView` is not a `ViewGroup` so you can not add view inside it .. APART from that you question is not clear enough .

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: check the answer if it is ok for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add only one CardView, you can add a cardView under your LinearLayout and set Visibility gone. Then when user click your recyclerview item, you can fill that cardView and set visible it.

If you want to add dynamically CardViews for each click to item, then you can add dynamically to your LinearLayout when your recycleview item clicked like;

```
 layout.addView(yourCardView);
```